# Push to GitHub error: Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults

Tags: git, github, git-push

I don't know, what is going on, I got no response from github. I tried a git push for the first time in a month or so and got this. Turned on export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 and did a push and get this:

```
localhost:send2mobile_rails phil$ git push
Password: 
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 207.97.227.239... * Connected to github.com (207.97.227.239) port 443 (#0)
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: O=*.github.com; OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.github.com
*    start date: 2009-12-11 05:02:36 GMT
*    expire date: 2014-12-11 05:02:36 GMT
*    subjectAltName: github.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority; serialNumber=07969287
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /303devworks/send2mobile_rails.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.1
Host: github.com
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< Server: nginx/0.7.61
< Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 10:53:13 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 0
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Repository"
< 
* Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://303devworks@github.com/MYUSERHERE/send2mobile_rails.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack'
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host github.com
* Connected to github.com (207.97.227.239) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user '303devworks'
> GET /303devworks/send2mobile_rails.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic MzAzZGVfd29sa3M6Y29nbmwzNzIw
User-Agent: git/1.7.1
Host: github.com
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/0.7.61
< Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 10:53:13 GMT
< Content-Type: application/x-git-receive-pack-advertisement
< Connection: keep-alive
< Status: 200 OK
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Length: 153
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< 
* Expire cleared
* Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
Counting objects: 166, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (133/133), done.
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 207.97.227.239... * connected
* Connected to github.com (207.97.227.239) port 443 (#0)
* SSL re-using session ID
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Server certificate:
*    subject: O=*.github.com; OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.github.com
*    start date: 2009-12-11 05:02:36 GMT
*    expire date: 2014-12-11 05:02:36 GMT
*    subjectAltName: github.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority; serialNumber=07969287
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'MYUSERHERE'
> POST /303devworks/send2mobile_rails.git/git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic JzAzZGV1d29ya3M6Y25nb29zNzIq
User-Agent: git/1.7.1
Host: github.com
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-receive-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-receive-pack-result
Expect: 100-continue
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

* The requested URL returned error: 411
* Closing connection #0
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411
Writing objects: 100% (140/140), 2.28 MiB | 1.93 MiB/s, done.
Total 140 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)
^C
localhost:send2mobile_rails phil$
```

Comment: Can you not use the ssh? path and push using that rather than http?

Comment: Potential original case on GitHub support: http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/3106-error-rpc-failed-result22-http-code-411

Comment: Eclipse Users, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606337/411-length-required-exception-when-pushing-to-github-from-eclipse/16795218#16795218

Comment: A dirty workaround is to push only a few files at a time if you are trying to push many at once. This way the server will be able to handle them. The best thing is to update the git settings.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and believe that it has to do with the size of the repo (edited- or the size of a particular file) you are trying to push.

Basically I was able to create new repos and push them to github. But an existing one would not work.

The HTTP error code seems to back me up it is a 'Length Required' error. So maybe it is too large to calc or greated that the max. Who knows.

EDIT

> I found that the problem may be
>   files that are large. I had one update
>   that would not push even though I had
>   successful pushes up to that point.
>   There was only one file in the commit
>   but it happened to be 1.6M
>
> So I added the following config change
>
> git config http.postBuffer 524288000
>
> To allow up to the file size 500M and
>   then my push worked. It may have been
>   that this was the problem initially
>   with pushing a big repo over the http
>   protocol.

END EDIT

the way I could get it to work (EDIT before I modified postBuffer) was to tar up my repo, copy it to a machine that can do git over ssh, and push it to github. Then when you try to do a push/pull from the original server it should work over https. (since it is a much smaller amount of data than an original push).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` command worked for me!

Comment: Importantly, the http.postBuffer config only works when pushing via http(s). Thats how I solved it - set the config as stated, but then added the http(s) address as another remote and pushed to it.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same issue.  This is how I solved my problem.

1. I increased the buffer size

   git config http.postBuffer 524288000
2. Then I  checked the users in the server and my user name was removed.  So I recreated the file using following command `sudo htpasswd -c /etc/users dilip_rajkumar`

Hope this helps some one..

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to push using "[smart http(s) protocol](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html)", which [GitHub now supports](http://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support).
Let's suppose here you have no proxy issue, or firewall problem.

What is your remote upstream repo address?
(what `git remote -v show` lists?)

I would recommend:

- making sure using an address like: https://gitbug/username/repo.git
- having a `~/.netrc` file with

```
    machine github.com
    login your_github_login
    password your_github_password
```

- try cloning again your repo `git clone https://github.com/your_github_login/gitrepo.git`, and push through that instance.

---

Note: as [Noufal Ibrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229602/noufal-ibrahim) comments, you could use ssh (unless ssh port is blocked, leaving you only with http/https connections)

```
git clone ssh://user@server:project.git
```

Comment: tried doing a .netrc file and still get this output: * Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host github.com


I also tried cloning again to new directory.  still no go.  Guess I'll try ssh, although not a fan of the SSH setup.

Comment: gave up on github, trying beanstalk now.

Comment: @phil: I confirm I wasn't able to use the `.netrc` file either. I had to include my GitHub password directly in the `remote.url` config value (in my local Git repo config): `https://username:password@github.com/username/repo.git`: it then works flawlessly.

Comment: `https://username@github.com/username/repo.git` works with `git` v1.7.1, but it'll prompt you for the password when pulling and pushing.

Comment: @l0b0: then you need a .netrc or _netrc file, as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899829/github-need-login-in-console-only-for-one-repo/7899895#7899895

Answer (score 2):

For those having trouble creating a new .netrc file, verify that it is in your HOME directory (cd ~/), make sure it is readable by you (chmod 600 ~/.netrc), and make sure it looks like this:

machine github.com 
login yourgithublogin
password yourgithubpassword