# Git hooks doesn't work on remote repository

Tags: git, apache, samba, githooks

I have a remote Git bare repository hosted on Ubuntu Linux virtual machine with Apache on it and accessible over http in local network.
When I configured my server I used this manual: http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2012/07/23/installing-a-git-server-using-apache-webdav-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/

I intend to propagate this repository to my website (wich have non-bare repository), while Ubuntu has access to it's directory over a Samba share.

So, have something like this:

|my PC| ==push==> |http://user@myhub.git/myproject.git| ==(post-receive hook)==> |/samba/mywebsite/|

My thought was to write a post-receive hook which will do something like that when I push changes from my IDE (PhpStorm):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Pulling content from hub to website"
echo "Pulling content from hub to website" >> /tmp/git.log
cd /samba/mywebsite/ || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull hub master

cd /var/www/myproject.git
git update-server-info
```

Of course, before that I declared inside my website repository:

```
git remote add hub /var/www/myproject.git
```

The problem is that my post-receive hook doesn't run when I perform push from my IDE: I do not see any result of written in first to lines with echoes (nor in IDE log, nor in /tmp/git.log file). Note, that push itself performs successfully.

In fact, the problem is much deeper: hooks doesn't launch at all. I tried post-receive, update and post-update hooks, but nothing... I placed line like "echo 111>>/tmp/git.log" in every one of them, but nothing happens.

Furthermore, when I try to launch one these hooks manualy, everything works fine and webside recevies updates:

```
sudo -u www-data ./post-receive
```

Of course, I do have read/write/execute permitions for user www-data, and also www-data owns everything in /var/www directory. Actually, I set 0777 permissions for all content in that directory.

I tried to perform git push origin manually and from IDE - same result.
I tried even to use !#/bin/sh and !#/bin/bash - no effect.

## UPD:

I performed this on my server:

```
cd ~
git clone /var/www/myproject.git
cd myproject
echo "newline">>README.txt
commit -a -m "Test commit"
git push origin
```

And miracle happend - it worked! I saw answer from the main repo and hooks did perfomed in this order: update, post-receive, post-update.

So, I assume, I have some problem with pushing changes over http. But I have no idea why does it so.

Comment: does www-data have write access to /samba/mywebsite? What is the path of your post-receive hook file?

Comment: Yes, www-data has write permissions for /samba/mywebsite. Actually, when I mount it, I set all permissions to 0777. And when I do something there under "sudo -u www-data", like creating new file, it works perfectly.
In addition, as I wrote, when I run "sudo -u www-data /var/www/myproject.git/hooks/post-receive", it does perform what I created it for (writing changes to my website dir).
Post-receive hook file path is /var/www/myproject.git/hooks/post-receive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push over HTTP not activating remote hooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372306/git-push-over-http-not-activating-remote-hooks)

Comment: git hooks don’t work over webdav, see the linked question.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think, that it is the same problem.

Comment: Actually, after following that simple instruction on http://git-scm.com/2010/03/04/smart-http.html everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a duplicate of [Git push over HTTP not activating remote hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372306/git-push-over-http-not-activating-remote-hooks).

In short, Git has to be configured as described [here](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/04/smart-http.html).