# Git server side hooks commit update file

Tags: git, githooks

I am trying to implement git hook commit on a server using these instructions: https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy

I created file "update" (make it executable, put in hooks folder), and found that this file is not executed when I do `git commit -m "my message"` and `git push` - all these commands work perfectly, but 'update' file is not working (I tried with simple script "echo "Hello World" >> somefile.txt)

Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you put the hook into the remote (server) repository? And certainly, update hooks works only on the remote side, on receiving commits from a client, so `git commit` isn't involved at all.

Comment: Yes, I put hook "update" file on server, but it does not work when I "git commit"!

Comment: `git commit` is a completely _local_ operation. It doesn't involve any network transaction, only `git push`, `git fetch` and `git pull` which is essentially `git fetch` + `git merge` do.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the hooks?

Comment: I want to implement that all commits begin with ticket numbers: "TicketNumber-1234"

I understand that "git commit" is local one. When I do "git push", my "update" script is not running at all. 

My repo path is /path/test.git/hooks - there I put "update" file.

Comment: I found similar ticket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372306/git-push-over-http-not-activating-remote-hooks  = same case as I described above. But when I switched to SSH protocol, it does not work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As commented above, the [`update` hook is a server side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks)

It needs to be on the server you are pushing to, in the bare repo: `repo.git/hook/update`

That explains why a `git commit` (local operation) does not trigger the server side hook.

For the rest, see the [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34177811/6309).