# Git push over SSH is not activating remote hooks

Tags: git, ssh, push, githooks

I have the following problems that **git push over SSH is not activating remote hooks**.

The server where Git repo is Linux ubuntu.
Git version 1.7.9.5
My path to repo hooks **`/path/test.git/hooks/update`**; with `Update` executable (`chmod +x`)

In **`update`** file I put just simple check to be sure it works.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World"
echo "098" >> test.txt
exit 1
```

I am connecting from Ubuntu (on Virtualbox) with following steps:

```
touch somefile.txt
git add -A
git commit -ma "my somefile add
```

Then:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

Counting objects: 3, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 291 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: new: 1, refs: 1, done
remote:
remote: New Changes:
remote:   https://URL/gerrit/15676
remote:
To ssh://mylogin@URL:29418/reponame
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/for/master
```

As you see my update script is not activated during "push".

What could be check why it happens like this?

Comment: Is your `test.git/hooks/update` on the server to which you are pushing to? (ie the `ssh://mylogin@URL:29418/reponame`)

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1   64 Dec  8 16:03 update

Comment: Is it one the server though? Meaning: if you log in onto that server, and cd to the bare repo, (`cd /path/to/test.git`), does a `git log` returns the newly pushed commit?

Comment: yes, it shows correctly all commits that was done.

Comment: And `/path/to/test.git` is on the server where you push to? (not on the worstation where you did commit). In that `/path/to/test.git` on the server, do you see `hooks/update`? (without any extension). And `update`, not `Update` (all lowercase letters)

Comment: /path/to/test.git is on server I push to.

Comment: OK: and you do have a `hooks/update` file there? (not `Update`, or `update.sh`)

Comment: update file is at hooks folder on server too and without extension.

Comment: Just for testing, can you rename your `update` script into `pre-receive`?

Comment: I renamed to pre-receive(chmod +x) , but it is the same result :(

Comment: Local "git push" activates hooks.