# "411 Length Required" Exception when pushing to Github from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

I am working on an Android app in Eclipse for a school project and trying to push to Github. It was working fine for a while, then suddenly it started telling me " An internal Exception occurred during push: http://github.com/[my user name]/[repo name].git: 411 Length Required"

I didn't change any of my settings in Eclipse or Git, so I'm not sure why it worked for one push but not the next. I was even more confused when Google told me that the '411 Length Required' exception was usually an HTTP-related problem.

If it helps, I've double checked my settings in Eclipse several times, it's running on an http protocol, secure store is always disabled, and Dry-Runs always seem to work fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Steve

Comment: Having the same issue, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949128/git-push-problem-argh
Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eclipse>Preferences>Team>Git>Configuration>Add Entry

Enter `http.postBuffer` as key and `524288000` as value (if 500M is enough)

Did the trick for me.