# Make git revert to SSLv3 when TLSv1 fails with "Ignored Unknown Record"

Tags: git, libcurl

Can't use `git`:

```
git clone https://github.com/foo/bar
```

fails:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/foo/bar': Unknown SSL  protocol error in connection to github.com:443
```

How can I force `git` to use SSLv3? I tried to compile git from source, but there is no setting beyond: `--with-openssl` (default). Adding the following line before line 408 in `remote-curl.c` doesn't work either:

```
 curl_easy_setopt(slot->curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3);
```

Here are some clues:

- **case 1**: When my browser tries to get to `https://github.com/foo/bar`, it first tries TLSv1. Handshake seems to be OK: Server key exchange, server hello done (at Wireshark). But it follows by "Ignored Unknown Record" from server and finally "Connection Reset" from server. Then A new connection but with SSLv3 kicks in and every thing is fine (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNjOH.png)).
- **case 2**: `curl` fails using TLSv1

  ```
  curl https://github.com/foo/bar
  ```

  fails:

  ```
  curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
  ```

  Setting `--sslv3` fixes the problem.
- **case 3**: Take this one

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:cassou/emacs
  ```

  fails:

  ```
  pycurl.error: (35, 'gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.')
  ```

**Edit**: curl 7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1.

**Edit**: debug information

```
Cloning into 'bar'...
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.30.252.130... * Connected to github.com (192.30.252.130) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
* Closing connection #0
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/foo/bar/': Unknown SSL       protocol error in connection to github.com:443
```

Comment: What version of Git are you using? What version of curl? What OS? Linux? Windows? Cygwin?

Comment: Please add debug information using `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`

Comment: I downloaded the git source code from github. curl 7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1.

Comment: Are you manually setting CAfile/CApath? Check your `git config`

Comment: Is there anything unorthodox about your connection? Do you require a proxy? VPN? Do you usually have HTTPS issues?

Comment: I CAN get to github without proxy (home connection). But I know that a lot of filtering with lots of transparent proxies and whatever happen in my country. They hate HTTPS. Did you see the picture?

Comment: There might be some SSL tampering going on there. Can you pastebin the SSL cert fingerprints?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? How can I get that? I have Wireshark. I can dump the pcap.

Comment: @YasserMZadeh check your `http.sslcainfo` git config (see my edited answer below)

Comment: @YasserMZadeh pcap dump would be great. Feel free to anonimize it though, keeping the relevant stuff intact.

Comment: @Yucal Adam Here is the pcap (accessing https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery) : https://app.box.com/s/9sogi1ja7rr24stbr5zo

Comment: From a quick glance I don't see any signs of malicious behavior, though I might be missing something.

Comment: Git 2.6 will provide a new interesting option: see [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20734176/6309)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update August 2015: Git 2.6+ (Q3 2015) will allow to specify the SSL version explicitly:

> ## `http`: add support for specifying the SSL version

See [commit 01861cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01861cb7a27b948bc0218877311f531f25386691) (14 Aug 2015) by [Elia Pinto (`devzero2000`)](https://github.com/devzero2000).
Helped-by: [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ed070a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed070a40072f01aa819f114bf6b35edf0f53cab2), 26 Aug 2015)</sup>

```
http.sslVersion
```

> The SSL version to use when negotiating an SSL connection, if you want to force the default.
>   The available and default version depend on whether libcurl was built against NSS or OpenSSL and the particular configuration of the crypto library in use. Internally this sets the '`CURLOPT_SSL_VERSION`' option; see the libcurl documentation for more details on the format of this option and for the ssl version supported.
>   Actually the possible values of this option are:
>
> - sslv2
> - sslv3
> - tlsv1
> - tlsv1.0
> - tlsv1.1
> - tlsv1.2
>
> Can be overridden by the '`GIT_SSL_VERSION`' environment variable.
>   To force git to use libcurl's default ssl version and ignore any explicit `http.sslversion` option, set 'GIT_SSL_VERSION' to the empty string.

---

Original answer Dec: 2013

I usually see that error message when my PROXY environment variables aren't properly set:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.mycompany.com:port
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.mycompany.com:port
export NO_PROXY=.mycompany.com
```

You can also [setup a `~/.netrc file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2949418/6309) for your GitHub credentials.

Make sure your **`git config http.sslcainfo`** does reference your **`/path/to/git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt`**, in order for curl to be able to validate the certificate associated to the GitHub server.

---

One workaround, if https really doesn't work, is to use an ssh url

```
git clone ssh://user@server:project.git
```

(if you have generated a private and public key first, and registered that public key to your GitHub account)

Comment: Thanks. That workaround worked. But I have the same issue with "bower install jquery" which fails:  retry Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery failed with ECONNRESET. (That picture was from this command actually, not git). I can access that link without proxy but with SSLv3.

Comment: @YasserMZadeh strange. I saw this with https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/631, related to network issues.