# git clone does nothing (same for push) on Mac OS X

Tags: git, macos

More specifically, whenever I type:

```
git clone https://github.com/lord/slate slate
```

The resulting output is:

```
Cloning into 'slate'...
```

However, the directory 'slate' is not created and nothing was received. If I enable the curl trace log by typing this:

```
GIT_TRACE_CURL=1 git clone https://github.com/lord/slate slate
```

The resulting output is this:

```
Cloning into 'slate'...

16:19:21.978835 http.c:638              == Info: Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults

16:19:22.064932 http.c:638              == Info:   Trying 192.30.253.113...

16:19:22.065011 http.c:638              == Info: TCP_NODELAY set

16:19:22.178879 http.c:638              == Info: Connected to github.com >

(192.30.253.113) port 443 (#0)
```

I recently installed Mac OS X Sierra, but I had the same problem before the update. I also updated the git version recently and I am right now using version 2.13.1 (although I was also experiencing the same problem with the previous version).

Did anyone else experience the same issue and maybe found the reason that was causing it?

**EDIT**

In the case of 'git push', the following command, executed in a local repository with committed changes:

> git push origin master

Outputs the following text:

> * Couldn't find host git2-rdlab.cs.upc.edu in the .netrc file; using defaults
>
> *   Trying 147.83.29.205...
>
> * TCP_NODELAY set
>
> * Connected to git2-rdlab.cs.upc.edu (147.83.29.205) port 80 (#0)
>
> > GET /jesusdz/PaperGradients.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: git2-rdlab.cs.upc.edu
>
> User-Agent: git/2.13.1
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>
> < Date: Fri, 21 Jul 2017 17:14:14 GMT
>
> < Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>
> < Location: https://git2-rdlab.cs.upc.edu/jesusdz/PaperGradients.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
>
> < Vary: Accept-Encoding
>
> < Content-Encoding: gzip
>
> < Content-Length: 234
>
> < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>
> <
>
> * Ignoring the response-body
>
> * Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
>
> * Connection #0 to host git2-rdlab.cs.upc.edu left intact
>
> * Issue another request to this URL: 'https://git2-rdlab.cs.upc.edu/jesusdz/PaperGradients.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack'
>
> * Couldn't find host git2-rdlab.cs.upc.edu in the .netrc file; using defaults
>
> *   Trying 147.83.29.205...
>
> * TCP_NODELAY set
>
> * Connected to git2-rdlab.cs.upc.edu (147.83.29.205) port 443 (#1)

I think that the problem is related to the part that says the following (although I am not sure):

> - Ignoring the response-body
> - Curl_http_done: called premature == 0

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Push to GitHub error: Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949128/push-to-github-error-couldnt-find-host-github-com-in-the-netrc-file-using-de)

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or firewall?

Comment: can you `ping github.com`?

Comment: @HugodoCarmo No, I am not behind any proxy or firewall.

Comment: @Nogoseke, yes, I can ping github.com.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, I think it is not a duplicate of the question you suggest. I edited the text to further explain some more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found an issue following what you've queried:

```
kurtis.rogers@AB-Trading02 ~ $ mkdir test
kurtis.rogers@AB-Trading02 ~ $ cd test
kurtis.rogers@AB-Trading02 test $ git clone https://github.com/lord/slate
Cloning into 'slate'...
remote: Counting objects: 2027, done.
remote: Total 2027 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2027
Receiving objects: 100% (2027/2027), 854.48 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1003/1003), done.
kurtis.rogers@AB-Trading02 test $
```

It most likely is an issue with your OS. I'd try to doing a complete, clean reinstall and be wary of changing system files, not assuming you have!

It could also be that when you clone this directory, it creates a directory called slate by default:

Try just `$ git clone git clone https://github.com/lord/slate`

Make a new directory somewhere, `cd` into it and see if that works?

Hope you can get it working!

Comment: I tried without explicitly specifying the name of the output directory and executing the command from a new directory. It did nothing. Yes, if I cannot solve the problem I am probably going to reinstall the system...

Comment: Use the git that comes with XCode.  Then you just need to uninstall and reinstall XCode, not the whole system.